# How to add physics to a turtle in python

Tags: python, game-physics, physics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm creating a game in python that you can move around and try to collect points by colliding with a coin. I want to add 2D physics to it to make it realistic. Is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Seems like some cool stuff. But why not use pygame?

Comment: I don't know how to use pygame. Btw can you use turtles in pygame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it:
The explanation is inside the code.

```
#Importing all the modules
import turtle
from turtle import *
import math

#Creating the screen
screen=Screen()

#Creating the turtle
vector1=Turtle("classic")
vector1.speed(-1)
vector1.penup()

#Declaring all the needed variables
Vx=0
Vy=0
V=0
A=0

#Starting the while loop
while True:

    #Updating the screen for better preformence
    screen.update()

    #Carculating the velocity
    V=math.sqrt(Vx**2+Vy**2)

    #Carculating the angle
    if Vx!=0:
        A=math.degrees(math.atan(Vy/Vx))
        if Vy<0 and Vx<0 or Vy>0 and Vx<0:
            A=A-180
    elif Vy <0:
        A=270
    else:
        A=90

#Moving the turtle    
    vector1.seth(A)
    vector1.fd(V)

#Changing the values of the velocities
    Vy-=0.5
    if Vx>0:
        Vx-=0.2
    elif Vx<0:
        Vx+=0.2
```

If there are any questions, please ask!

Answer (score 1):

The nature of simulations is that they are different than reality. As we perform a simulation, we create a mathematical model of the behavior of objects. Let's consider simulation of gravity. We define a ball, then we displace the location of the ball as time flows. Newton modeled the falling of a ball by `x=gt^2`. Therefore we must define an acceleration for the ball towards the ground. Much more information about simulation is available [in this video](https://youtu.be/-nbTrPwQudo).

You can use this code in order to simulate gravity:

```
yvel=5*(time()-start_t)
```

where `time()` cames from `from time import time`

Comment: But what about the x-axis? I need it too.

Comment: @JonathanDrukker There is no gravitational effect through x-axis. Therefore you can either define new force field either you can make user controlled speed control system

Comment: But in the game the turtle is going to move itself on the x-axis